# Piping local stdin to 'heroku run' - mustn't write to stdout? 4k stdout buffer?

Tags: ruby, heroku, stdin, heroku-toolbelt, thor

I'm using thor to write command-line tasks (in a rails 3 app) and trying to pipe input to them over heroku, e.g. `cat somefile.csv | heroku run thor sometask`

works great on my local machine `cat somefile.csv | thor sometask` but can fail on heroku. Some versions of sometasks work occasionally, other ones always fail at a specific point -- 1 issue is that the `cat somefile.csv` is being echoed to the console while it is being consumed by the `thor sometask` (this only happens over heroku, so I presume this is internal to heroku CLI).

I have found a workaround, which is to ensure that I'm writing nothing to the console (stdout) in the thor tasks & the functions they call, but it's frustrating to have to do that (no progress indication etc).

Another "workaround" is to ensure that the file being sent is under 4k (4095bytes) - I haven't been able to make it fail with this

Any ideas why this is happening (and why the cat is being echoed to stdout)? Is there a 4k stdout buffer limit for example somewhere in communication process? Any way to make the heroku  CLI less verbose?

Answer (score 0):

If you use your workaround of "writing nothing to the console" and instead of `cat` use `pv`, you'll be able to see a progress indicator.

This is what the output might look like:

```
$ pv somefile.csv | heroku run thor sometask
3.12MiB 0:00:00 [25.9MiB/s] [===============================================================================================================>] 100%
```